# Binding selected item in ComboBox in WinUI3

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, winui-3, winui

I've a ComboBox in WinUI3 with two items manual added:

```
<ComboBox Width="200" SelectedItem="{Binding MyProp, Mode=TwoWay}">
   <ComboBoxItem Content="1"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="2"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Even if `MyProp` is set to "1" or "2" initially, the Combobox's text is empty. No item is selected. And if I select one of these items during runtime as user, the value is not written back into `MyProp`.

But the binding and ViewModel works fine, since a TextBox with the same TwoWay-Binding is working fine in both directions:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyProp, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
```

Do I've to bind the items itself too via a list in the view model? Hoped, to define two ComboboxItem in the XAML is enough.

Comment: You should bind to `SelectedValue` instead since "1" != `ComboBoxItem`

Comment: Nope. Has no effect. If I bind it via SelectedValue, each change of MyProp clears the ComboBox but does not set the correct value.

Comment: Yes, you are right That will break in the reverse this time  ComboBoxItem  != "1". It seems there is no easy way to accomplish this. Either you should use the items source or create a weird value converter that converts between ComboBoxItem string and vice versa.

Comment: If you bind to Text and set IsEditable to true, it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `ComboBoxItem` as items, you need to target the `Content` property. This should work:

```xml
<ComboBox
    SelectedValue="{Binding MyProp, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedValuePath="Content">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="2" />
</ComboBox>
```

But you can avoid using `ComboBoxItem` explicitly and make it simple:

```xml
<ComboBox
    SelectedValue="{Binding MyProp, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <x:String>1</x:String>
    <x:String>2</x:String>
</ComboBox>
```